# Character replacement not working, outputting close to expected output

Tags: javascript

I have a script (which I got from another stack overflow user) that I modified slightly, and for some reason, one which I can not find out, the script is outputting something different. (please don't run this is you have a slow computer: the github file contains over 350000 words)

```
const url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwyl/english-words/master/words_alpha.txt';
fetch(url).then(d => d.text()).then(d => d.replace(/\s/g, '')).then(d => d.replace(/\n/g, ' ')).then(d => d.replace(/\s/g, "', '"));
```

An example of the output is `'aardvark', '', 'apple'` (just an example), when it should be `'aardvark', 'apple'`. Does anybody know why this happens, or how to fix it?

Comment: Questions should be self-contained. Please give a [mcve], one that doesn't rely on an external file.

Comment: John, are you going to be able to put a file containing over 350000 words in a stack overflow question?

Comment: No -- note the "minimal" in [mcve]. It is up to you to find an easily reproducible program which illustrates your bug.

Comment: The whole script relies on the "fetch(url)" object.

Comment: @AndrewL64 you have a point to do. Finding a [mcve] is often easier said than done.

Comment: But you're here not to answer but critique? I think that's the opposite of Stack Overflow.

Comment: FYI, `\s` matches `\n`, so after running `d.replace(/\s/g, '')`, the string won't contain any whitespace anymore. In other words, `.then(d => d.replace(/\n/g, ' ')).then(d => d.replace(/\s/g, "', '"))` does nothing to the input.

Comment: @FelixKling note: I take away any extra whitespace _before_ replacing `\n` with `' '`, aka get rid of `\s`, make `\s`, replace `\s`.

Comment: The point of comments is to suggest ways to make a question more answerable. The problem looks like one involving regular expressions, not the fetch(url) object per se.

Comment: *"I take away any extra whitespace before replacing \n with ' '"* Exactly. **A line break is whitepace too** and thus removed. Try it: `"foo bar\nbay baz".replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/\n/g, ' ').replace(/\s/g, "', '")`.

Comment: @EthanSlota, a more approachable way to ask this question would have been to create a similar, much smaller file and use that one in the snippet.

Comment: @FelixKling that didn't work. `Uncaught TypeError: fetch(...).replace is not a function` Note I am basing this off fetch().

Comment: I was just providing an example that demonstrates that your logic doesn't work. It doesn't matter were the data comes from. Of course `fetch(...).replace` doesn't work, `fetch` does not return a string. I only reduced your code to a self contained example (a [mcve] if you will). But if you don't get my point then I don't know what else to do to make you understand.

Comment: Ok then, I can translate that myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, running `d.replace(/\s/g, '')` would remove all space *and* newlines from `d`, and so I'll assume you meant `d.replace(/ /g, '')`.

It seems like the file has 3 consecutive spacing characters after each word, which means that the first `replace` would only remove one space. To fix this, you can unify the first and second `replace`s by using negation:

```js
const url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwyl/english-words/master/words_alpha.txt';

fetch(url)
 .then(d => d.text())
 .then(d => d.replace(/[^\n]\s/g, ''))
 .then(d => d.replace(/\s/g, "', '"))
 .then(console.log);
    //=> Should print out the words in the expected format.
```

The reason why the code above is because the first `replace` remove all spaces (that aren't newlines) and the second replaces every newline character with `', '`.

One way to make this more readable and robust would be to use `.split` instead of `.replace`:

```js
const url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwyl/english-words/master/words_alpha.txt';

fetch(url)
 .then(d => d.text())
 .then(d => d.split(/\s+/g))
 .then(d => d.map(word => `'${word}'`))
 .then(d => d.join(', '))
 .then(console.log);
    //=> Should still print out the words correctly.
```

The second option is a bit better since it is properly formatted (the first word has an opening `'` before it and the last word has a closing `'` after it).